# Avoid repeating an expression in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: optimization, linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
val = val.Select(item => new SimpleBill { CTime = item.CTime, Description = item.Description, ID = item.ID,
      IDAccount = item.IDAccount, OrderNumber = item.OrderNumber, PSM = item.PSM, Sum = item.Sum,
      Type = (BillType)item.Type,
      ByteStatus = ((Bill)item).Payments.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.ID).FirstOrDefault().Status,
      LastPaymentDate = ((Bill)item).Payments.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.ID).FirstOrDefault().CTime,
      LastPaymentSum = ((Bill)item).Payments.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.ID).FirstOrDefault().Sum });
      }
```

Is it possible to avoid repeating the `((Bill)item).Payments.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.ID).FirstOrDefault()` part 3 times? I tried turning it into a method and into a delegate - the code compiled in both cases, but produced an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `let` contstruct as follows:

```
val = from item in val
let lastPayment = ((Bill)item).Payments
   .OrderByDescending(payment => payment.ID)
   .FirstOrDefault()
select new SimpleBill
{
    lastPayment.CTime,
    //Rest of fields
}
```

However, as you may noticed this uses the LINQ Query syntax vs. Method syntax. IIRC `let` is only available in the former.

Comment: Thank you! With the help of http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2009/10/07/using-let-in-linq-with-extension-method-syntax.aspx I managed to rewrite it using the method syntax: `val = val.Select(bill => new { Bill = bill, LastPayment = ((Bill)item).Payments.OrderByDescending(payment => payment.ID).FirstOrDefault() })
      .Select(item => new SimpleBill
      {
      LastPaymentDate = item.LastPayment.CTime,
      //Rest of fields
      });`